# Width change of a view is not reflected in UI even though view.isInLayout is true

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I'm changing the width of a view and using `view.isInLayout` to decide whether to call `requestLayout()` or not.

But in some cases, even if `view.isInLayout` returns `true` in the function which updates the width, the width is not updated in UI.

Calling `requestLayout()` after updating the width, irrespective of layout's state makes the UI update as expected

However, requestLayout's official [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#requestLayout()) states, This (requestLayout) should not be called while the view hierarchy is currently in a layout pass.

Answer (score 0):

Width and height of any view can be change by changing its layout params

```
 val layoutParams = LayoutParams(WIDTH, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
 view.layoutParams = layoutParams
```

here view is your view(imageview/textview/LinearLayout etc)